# How to share code between iOS and Mac on .NET MAUI? (no conditional compilation and no code repeat)

Tags: c#, ios, .net, macos, maui

Let's say I defined a partial class on each platform, which defines an "initialize" method, and I call that method from my shared context.

I defined that partial class on Android and Windows platform (same class name and namespace).

But since both it's Mac & iOS implementations have the same code, I wouldn't like to define it twice (on Mac and iOS platform folders).

I followed this guide: https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting.md

With it's help, I applied "folder-based multi-targeting" and created a "MaciOS" platform folder, to define my partial class there.

Problem is my shared context says there is no implementation on iOS and Mac platforms. It makes sense, because iOS and Mac folders are empty, but MaciOS folder **has** the class.

Even, if I open my partial class implementation on the "MaciOS" folder, I have no intellisense and Visual Studio doesn't say the current platform. Instead, it says "Miscellaneous Files".

How can I share Mac & iOS code without using conditional compilation, and without repeating code?

Edit:
My "folder-based multi-targeting" looks like this:

```
<!-- Android -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-android')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\Android\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\Android\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Both iOS and Mac Catalyst -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-ios')) != true AND $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-maccatalyst')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\MaciOS\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\MaciOS\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- iOS -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-ios')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\iOS\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\iOS\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Mac Catalyst -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-maccatalyst')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\MacCatalyst\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\MacCatalyst\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Windows -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\Windows\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\Windows\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Please show what the multi-targeting setup in your *.csproj* file looks like at the moment.

Comment: You will need conditional compilation for this

Comment: @FreakyAli Not necessarily, it can also be done with filename-based multi-targeting, but I would like to see the current setup first in order to be able to provide an answer based on that.

Comment: @Julian I see, would filename-based multi-targeting work for a single code base for iOS and Mac though?

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes. It's different from the folder-based approach. With filename-based multi-targeting you can define the conditions and filename filters yourself.

Comment: Interesting gonna wait for your answer in that case

Comment: @Julian I added it as an edit

Comment: @just_a_developer OK, and where did you add the code that you want to share? Did you create a new folder under the existing *Platforms* folder that you called *MaciOS*?

Comment: @Julian exactly!

Comment: @just_a_developer That's what I suspected, you cannot do that. See my answer for your options to solve this.

Comment: @Julian is it a bug? Shouldn't be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any details about your current multi-targeting setup so far, I will provide a more generic answer, but I'll try to address things based on your description.

## Multi-targeting approaches

With regards to multi-targeting you have two options in .NET MAUI:

1. Folder-based multi-targeting using the platform-specific folders
2. Filename-based multi-targeting using a specific filename convention

## Folder-based multi-targeting

There are two flavors of folder-based multi-targeting: built-in folders and custom folders.

### Built-in target platform folders

The first one comes directly built-in with any new .NET MAUI app project (provided you use one of the templates).

Here, everything is configured already and the *.csproj* file of your project doesn't contain any conditional item groups. This is what the pre-defined platform-specific folders under *YourProject/Platforms/* are for. In any new .NET MAUI project, you'll find the following folder structure:

```
YourProject
|- Platforms
   |- Android
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- iOS
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- MacCatalyst
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- Windows
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- Tizen
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
```

Here, you don't have to do anything except for placing the platform-specific implementations in the appropriate folders - no further configuration or conditional compilation required.

The down-side of this is that you cannot simply add different platforms or combine implementations of platforms by creating new target platform folders. They are not known or recognized by MAUI. For example, the following is **not** possible and will result in what you've described as the problem you're facing:

```
YourProject
|- Platforms
   |- Android
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- iOS
   |- MacCatalyst
   |- Windows
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- Tizen
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- MaciOS
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
```

This is likely what you've tried based on the limited information you've provided.

### Custom platform folders

The second flavor of folder-based multi-targeting requires configuration on your part, e.g. by specifying a convention for the folder structure to be used.

Instead of using the built-in folders, you can specify your own platform-specific implementation folders anywhere else in your project, e.g. like this:

```
YourProject
|- Platforms
|- MyAwesomeFeature
   |- Android
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- MaciOS
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
   |- Windows
      |- MyAwesomeFeature.cs
```

Notice I'm not using the standard *YourProject/Platforms/* folder, but a custom *YourProject/MyAwesomeFeature/* folder (right under *YourProject*).

In order to achieve this, you can set up conditional item groups in your *.csproj* (as described in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting#configure-filename-based-multi-targeting)):

```xml
<!-- Folder-based: Both iOS and Mac Catalyst -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-ios')) != true AND $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-maccatalyst')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\MaciOS\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\MaciOS\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Folder-based: Android -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-android'))">
    <Compile Remove="**\Android\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\Android\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Folder-based: Windows -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-windows'))">
    <Compile Remove="**\Windows\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="**\Windows\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now, with this approach, you can share the implementation for iOS and MacCatalyst - in some feature specific folder which is not in the default, built-in *Platforms* folder.

## Filename-based multi-targeting

Alternatively, you can use multi-targeting based on filenames, which often is easier to navigate and understand, but that depends on the complexity of the feature or APIs you're using.

In this case, you would not filter based on the folder name, but on the filename. Your folder structure could look like this with the following filenames:

```
YourProject
|- MyAwesomeFeature
   |- MyAwesomeFeature.android.cs
   |- MyAwesomeFeature.macios.cs
   |- MyAwesomeFeature.windows.cs
```

Here, the implementation files are all in the same folder, but they have different suffixes, while their class name and namespace declarations are identical.

To achieve this, you would set up the following conditonal item groups:

```xml
<!-- Filename-based: Both iOS and Mac Catalyst -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-ios')) != true AND $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-maccatalyst')) != true">
  <Compile Remove="**\**\*.macios.cs" />
  <None Include="**\**\*.macios.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Filename-based: Android -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net8.0-android')) != true">
  <Compile Remove="**\**\*.android.cs" />
  <None Include="**\**\*.android.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />  
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Filename-based: Windows -->
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows')) != true">
  <Compile Remove="**\*.windows.cs" />
  <None Include="**\*.windows.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

## Notes

You can combine both folder-based and filename-based approaches, but you cannot add new folders to the built-in *Platforms* directory.

Whichever option you should choose depends on your needs and your preference.

It's not always required to use `partial class` declarations for multi-targeting. This is only required if there is an overall API with a shared part as well as platform-specific parts.

Comment: I did the "Custom platform folders" you mention when I faced the problem. So, it didn't work.
Can it be achieved on any other way?
I don't understand why the MAUI team added support for "MaciOS" on the official documentation, if it doesn't work...

Comment: I tried it myself and it works fine with custom platform folders - as long as they're not under *Platforms*, as described. This is also how it works in the official documentation. You must still be doing something differently. Please add more details to your question, e.g. show the affected code as well as a screenshot or sketch of your folder structure.

Comment: wow, this is massive! Thank you so much!
I was using the standard "Platforms" folder. I'm dumb enough to not notice you didn't use it.
I think I will tell them to update their documentation with samples.
You explained it better than them!